# Corona SDK MOSQUITO killing game

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I'm very verv new to corona and developing game.

Question 1 : How do i stop the game when times up/user tap the bee/ life=0 and display a new scene called 'game over' ?

Question 2 : Whenever i pause the game, then click resume, the number of mosquitoes increases alot. How to change it?

local composer = require( "composer" )
    local scene = composer.newScene()

```
local physics = require("physics")
local widget = require "widget"
physics.start()
rand = math.random( 20 )

local slap_sound = audio.loadSound("Sound/slap2.mp3")
local ow = audio.loadSound("Sound/ow.mp3")
local buttonSound = audio.loadSound("Sound/sound2.mp3")
local background
local back
local count={total1=0,total=0,touch=0,life=3}
local total
local time_remain = 30
local mossie
local bee
local shade
local gameOverScreen
local winScreen
local gameIsActive = false
local countdown
local life
local pauseBtn
local resumeBtn
local gametmr
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- All code outside of the listener functions will only be executed ONCE
-- unless "composer.removeScene()" is called.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
local function countDown(e)
    time_remain = time_remain-1
    countdown.text = time_remain

    if time_remain == 0 then
        composer.gotoScene("gameover")
    end
end

local pauseGame = function(e)
    if(e.phase=="ended") then
        audio.play(buttonSound)
        physics.pause()
        timer.pause(gametmr)
        pauseBtn.isVisible = false
        resumeBtn.isVisible = true
        return true
    end
end

local resumeGame = function(e)
    if(e.phase=="ended") then
        audio.play(buttonSound)
        physics.start()
        timer.resume(gametmr)
        pauseBtn.isVisible = true
        resumeBtn.isVisible = false
        return true
    end
end

local collisionListener=function(self,event)
    if(event.phase=="began")then
        if(event.other.type=="mossie")then
            audio.play(ow)
            count.life=count.life-1
                --if(count.life==0) then

                --end   
            event.other:removeSelf()
            event.other=nil
        else
            event.other:removeSelf()
            event.other=nil
        end
    end 
end

function onTouch(mossie)
    audio.play(slap_sound)
    count.touch=count.touch+1
    total.text="Score : "..count.touch
    mossie.target:removeSelf()
end

function killIt(e)
    if(e.phase == "ended") then

    end
end

local bottomWall = function()
    botwall=display.newImage("Images/tangan.png")
    botwall.x = 160
    botwall.y = 500
    botwall:setFillColor(22,125,185,255)
    botwall.type="botwall"
    botwall.collision=collisionListener
    physics.addBody(botwall,"static",{ density=100.0, friction=0.0, bounce=0.0} )
    botwall:addEventListener("collision",botwall)
end

local function newMossie(event)    
    total.text="Score : "..count.touch
    life.text="Life : "..count.life
    mossie = display.newImage("Images/biasa.png") 
    mossie.x = 60 + math.random( 160 )
    mossie.y = -100
    mossie.type="mossie"
    mossie:setFillColor(255,0,0)
    physics.addBody( mossie, { density=0.3, friction=0.2, bounce=0.5} )
    mossie.name = "mossie"
    mossie:addEventListener("touch",onTouch)
end 

local function newBee(event)
    bee = display.newImage("Images/lebah.png")
    bee.x = 60 + math.random( 160 )
    bee.y = -100
    bee.type="other"
    physics.addBody( bee, { density=1.4, friction=0.3, bounce=0.2} )
    bee:addEventListener("touch",killIt)
end


-- local forward references should go here

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- "scene:create()"
function scene:create( event )

   local sceneGroup = self.view

   background = display.newImageRect( "Images/bg.jpg", display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
   background.anchorX = 0
   background.anchorY = 0
   background.x, background.y = 0, 0

   total=display.newText("Score : 0",display.contentWidth * 0.5, 20, "Arial", 26)
   total:setTextColor(000000)

   countdown=display.newText(time_remain ,display.contentWidth * 0.9, 20, "Arial", 26)
   countdown:setTextColor(000000)

   life = display.newText("Life : 3 " ,display.contentWidth * 0.5, 50, "Arial", 26)
   life:setTextColor(000000)

   pauseBtn = display.newImage("Images/pause.png")
   pauseBtn.x = display.contentWidth * 0.1
   pauseBtn.y = display.contentHeight - 450

   resumeBtn = display.newImage("Images/playb.png") 
   resumeBtn.x = display.contentWidth * 0.1
   resumeBtn.y = display.contentHeight - 450

   botwall=display.newImage("Images/tangan.png")
   botwall.x = 160
   botwall.y = 500
   botwall:setFillColor(22,125,185,255)
   botwall.type="botwall"
   botwall.collision=collisionListener
   physics.addBody(botwall,"static",{ density=100.0, friction=0.0, bounce=0.0} )


   sceneGroup:insert(background)
   sceneGroup:insert(total)
   sceneGroup:insert(countdown)
   sceneGroup:insert(life)
   sceneGroup:insert(pauseBtn)
   sceneGroup:insert(resumeBtn)
   sceneGroup:insert(botwall)

   resumeBtn.isVisible = false
   pauseBtn:addEventListener("touch", pauseGame)
   resumeBtn:addEventListener("touch", resumeGame)
   botwall:addEventListener("collision",botwall)

   -- Initialize the scene here.
   -- Example: add display objects to "sceneGroup", add touch listeners, etc.
end

-- "scene:show()"
function scene:show( event )

   local sceneGroup = self.view
   local phase = event.phase



   if ( phase == "will" ) then

      -- Called when the scene is still off screen (but is about to come on screen).
   elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
   dropMossie = timer.performWithDelay( 2000 , newMossie, -1 )
   dropBee = timer.performWithDelay( 1800 , newBee, -1)
   gametmr = timer.performWithDelay(1000, countDown, -1)


      -- Called when the scene is now on screen.
      -- Insert code here to make the scene come alive.
      -- Example: start timers, begin animation, play audio, etc.
   end
end

-- "scene:hide()"
function scene:hide( event )

   local sceneGroup = self.view
   local phase = event.phase



   if ( phase == "will" ) then




      -- Called when the scene is on screen (but is about to go off screen).
      -- Insert code here to "pause" the scene.
      -- Example: stop timers, stop animation, stop audio, etc.
   elseif ( phase == "did" ) then


      -- Called immediately after scene goes off screen.
   end
end

-- "scene:destroy()"
function scene:destroy( event )

   local sceneGroup = self.view
   physics.stop()
   timer.cancel(gametmr)
    pauseBtn:removeEventListener("touch", pauseGame)
   resumeBtn:removeEventListener("touch", resumeGame)
   botwall:removeEventListener("collision",botwall)
   bee:removeEventListener("touch",killIt)
   mossie:removeEventListener("touch",onTouch)
   -- Called prior to the removal of scene's view ("sceneGroup").
   -- Insert code here to clean up the scene.
   -- Example: remove display objects, save state, etc.
end

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Listener setup
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, make a new scene for gameOver. Make sure that you stop the all timers, nill them out. All that you used in this scene nill it out to avoid memory leaks. Just make a function that will do these in order for you to re-use it. And for the Question 2, you didn't pause dropBee and dropMossie thats why it your they multiply when you resume the game because the timer is still ticking.